# How to enable M out of N CloudWatch Alarm with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

[Since december 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-now-alerts-you-when-any-m-out-of-n-metric-datapoints-in-an-interval-are-above-your-threshold/) it's possible to have CloudWatch Alarm alarm triggered only if M out of N data points are breaching. When creating alarms with CloudFormation, the `CloudWatch::Alarm::EvaluationPeriods` influences (together with the period) the N in question.

By default, the Alarm is created with M = N. I couldn't find a way to change M, though. Is it not supported by CloudFormation yet?

Comment: It looks that way. `DatapointsToAlarm` is listed in the [PutMetricAlarm API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricAlarm.html) but it's missing from the [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's finally supported and officially documented. Thanks Tim Malone for pointing out the prop name.

> **DatapointsToAlarm**
>
> > The number of datapoints that must be breaching to trigger the alarm. This is used only if you are setting an "M out of N" alarm. In that case, this value is the M. For more information, see Evaluating an Alarm in the Amazon CloudWatch User Guide.
> >
> > Required: No
> >
> > Type: Integer
> >
> > Update requires: No interruption

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarm-datapointstoalarm